# Python error: the following arguments are required :

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, argparse

I am not familiar with Python, trying to build some DNN. So when I tried to parse some arguments I got this error in main.

```
usage: main.py [-h] [-j N] [--resume PATH] [--epochs N] [--start-epoch N] [-b N] [--lr LR]
               [--weight-decay W] [-e] [--print-freq N]
               DIR
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: DIR
```

Here is some part of the code:

```
# Parse arguments and prepare program
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Training and Using ColorNet')
parser.add_argument('data', metavar='DIR', help='path to dataset')
parser.add_argument('-j', '--workers', default=0, type=int, metavar='N', help='number of data loading workers (default: 0)')
parser.add_argument('--resume', default='', type=str, metavar='PATH', help='path to .pth file checkpoint (default: none)')
parser.add_argument('--epochs', default=50, type=int, metavar='N', help='number of total epochs to run')
parser.add_argument('--start-epoch', default=0, type=int, metavar='N', help='manual epoch number (overridden if loading from checkpoint)')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--batch-size', default=16, type=int, metavar='N', help='size of mini-batch (default: 16)')
parser.add_argument('--lr', '--learning-rate', default=0.1, type=float, metavar='LR', help='learning rate at start of training')
parser.add_argument('--weight-decay', '--wd', default=1e-10, type=float, metavar='W', help='weight decay (default: 1e-4)')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--evaluate', dest='evaluate', action='store_true', help='use this flag to validate without training')
parser.add_argument('--print-freq', '-p', default=10, type=int, metavar='N', help='print frequency (default: 10)')

# Current best losses
best_losses = 1000.0
use_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()

def main():
    global  args, best_losses, use_gpu
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print('Arguments: {}'.format(args))
```

I read some comments to change

```
 parser.parse_args()
```

to

```
parser.parse_args(args)
```

but it didn't work :)

Comment: If it is a really easy question sorry for bothering, I havent found any answer that's why I am here.

Comment: It seems you are not calling the script with these arguments, so try to execute it from `CMD` like: `my_file.py -j --resume ...`. Another easy way to try, is with VS Code, by setting your arguments in the *launch.json* file. And take care of the order and if they are optional or not, otherwise this error will be triggered again!

Comment: How are you calling this script?  When using `argparse` you need to provide `commandline arguments`.  If you don't know what those are, read up on them, or don't use `argparse`.

Comment: The first argument, `data` (`DIR`) is, what the `argparse` documentation calls a `positional` argument.  It requires a value.  The other arguments are `flagged`, indicated by the '--' flag string and some value.  They are optional, and get the `default` value if not provided by the user.  I don't know where you are getting this code, but you should complain to that source if this isn't clear.

Comment: https://github.com/lukemelas/Automatic-Image-Colorization/ it is about this repository, I tried to adapt this cnn based image colorization to my project @СергейКох

Comment: I see your code in the linked `main.py`.  That is a standalone python script that needs to be called from shell with the appropriate commandline arguments.  I don't see any examples of doing so; the author is assuming you know enough basic Python.  It's hard to use respositories like this without some prior Python knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

As DIR doesn't have a default value, you need to supply one when running the program. The easiest way to do this is via a command line interface. Consult the documentation of the library you are using for further hints on that.